# How to hide previous button on first fragment and next button on last fragment in viewpager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Here's my MainActivity that initiates Circlepageindicator.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
ViewPager pager;
Button prev,next;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     MyPagerAdapter adapter=new MyPagerAdapter();
     pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
     pager.setAdapter(adapter);     
     pager.setCurrentItem(0);

     //Bind the title indicator to the adapter
     CirclePageIndicator titleIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.titles);
     titleIndicator.setViewPager(pager);


     prev = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prev);   
     prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Do something in response to button click
                pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() - 1);

            }
        });

     next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
     next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Do something in response to button click
                pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() + 1);

            }
        });

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (pager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
        // If the user is currently looking at the first step, allow the system to handle the
        // Back button. This calls finish() on this activity and pops the back stack.
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        // Otherwise, select the previous step.
        pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
    }
}

}
```

I have Circlepageindicator working fine with previous and next buttons. But i want to hide previous button on first fragment and next button on last fragment. Newbie in this. Any suggestions are accepted. Thank you.

[image]

**Updated:**

Found solution.

```
CirclePageIndicator titleIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.titles);
     titleIndicator.setViewPager(pager);

     titleIndicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(pager.getCurrentItem() == 0)
            {
                prev.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if(pager.getCurrentItem() == 1)
            {
                prev.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if(pager.getCurrentItem() == 2)
            {
                prev.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                next.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Now on swipe and on button click, buttons show/hide at respective pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your onPageScrolled  method of OnPageChangeListener of ViewPager
titleIndicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new PagerChangeListener());

```
class PagerChangeListener implements OnPageChangeListener {
    @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

                pageSelected = arg0;

                switch (pageSelected) {
                case 0: {

                    preButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                    break;

                case 2: {

                    nexButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                    break;

                default: {
                    nexButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    preButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                    break;
                }

            }
}
```

Comment: If i set pager.OnPageChangeListener in MainActivity.java, CirclePageIndicator won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple... I hope it will work for you

just find

```
// For previous button
 if(pager.getCurrentItem() == 0)
{
previousBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

and

```
  // For Next Button
    if(pager.getCurrentItem() == YOUR LAST ITEM INDEX)
        {
        nextBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

I hope it will work for you...

and for more information just go through link:

http://dwij.co.in/greendroid-library-implementation-in-android-project/

Comment: Could you please explain me where to place the above code. My classes are MainActivity.java (pasted above),CirclePageIndicator.java,MyPagerAdapter.java and PageIndicator.java

Comment: Oh, It is in the MainActivity.java file on respective button onClickListener.

Comment: Buttons hide but they aren't appearing again if i swipe back. Even if i make them visible also.

Comment: ok then, for first and last index make it View.invisible and for inbetween index make it View.visible. Hope it will work.

Comment: Tried, but failed. This is onclick of button, i want that with swipe also. Should i write that in OnPageListener ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  This is my **MainActivity.java**

 final ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

     **pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()** 
    {
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                 if (position == 0) {
                    ivprvs.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    ivnxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                if (position == 1) {
                    ivprvs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ivnxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                if (position == 2) {
                    ivprvs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ivnxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```